# PowerPC distro with GPARTED

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gparted, resize

I'm looking for a PPC version of any Linux distro as a LiveCD image that has GPARTED.

I'm looking for GPARTED specifically because it will allow me to resize the partition on the HDD and I need it on a LiveCD because the HDD can't be mounted when I modify the partition table.

The GPARTED LiveCD only exists for x86 as far as I can tell.

I'm hoping that some older version of Ubuntu has this somewhere...

If there's another way to get a bootable version of Ubuntu with a partition editor of some kind for PowerPC that would work please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know there were live CDs for Power PCs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Ubuntu for [PowerPC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads)

Make sure to install `hfsprogs`since it is needed for gparted to work on a hfs partition.

Comment: Can hfsprogs be placed on a liveCD version of PPC Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes it ca you can, you can do sudo 'apt-get install hfsprogs'

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Ubuntu is not really the solution here.  (To  boot a Live Image on an iBook and use GParted on the internal SSD)

Here were my specifics:

- Needed to fix a partition table issue on an HFS formatted drive in an iBook G4 (removing the SSD is non-trivial)
- Goal was to be able to use GParted on the iBook
- Used UnetBootin to create a Live image on a USB key using 12.04 for PPC
- Live USB key created without issue using 12.04 PPC iso

The main blocker was that Ubuntu for PowerPC on this particular iBook model is not stable (12.04). Was not successful installing either Gparted or HFSprogs to the Live image as a result.

There may be an earlier version that is stable on this hardware but after some research I couldn't find a likely candidate.  I may go back one day and try prior versions of Ubuntu.

A secondary blocker though is the difficulty in getting a USB drive to boot the iBook.  it required issuing commands in the Open Firmware interface for the iBook.

I did come across a lot of opinions that Debian might be more PPC friendly though.  I may try that in addition to prior versions of Ubuntu.